# C# bluetooth connection between raspberry pi and PC

Tags: c#, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

***Complete noob Question***

I have a raspberry pi that I want to have a connection with my pc via Bluetooth so that they can send and receive data.

The raspberry pi will be running a winform application on it, using rasbian.

The data will be just simple strings of data
And both will be running a UI

Ideally, both can receive and send data to each other, but if such is not possible.

Or the PC is allowed to ask for data from the pi and the pi then sends it. 
So

Comment: how can rasbian run a winforms application?

Comment: No way to run WinForm on raspbian because mono does not support WinForms for now (I can be wrong but that is what I know). All you can do is to run Win 10 IoT on your RPi and then develop UWP or console application. Our Bluetooth Framework supports Win 10 IoT on Raspberry Pi so you can use it on both sides.

Comment: You can just copy it onto the Raspberrys pies SD card and run it from bash

Comment: [WinForms for Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/)

Comment: There is also an extension that lets you debug on a pie via SSH. 
Its Called VSMonoDebugger

Comment: Can you better describe your requirements: What sort of data should be exchange? Is it standardized data such a audio, files etc. or application specific? Which system will provide the data, which will consume it? Or is it a symmetric relationship? What sort of application is running on the Raspberry Pi and your PC? Do they both have a UI or is one of the "headless"?

Comment: Certainly i can do that